# Why is this js function returning undefined object?

Tags: javascript

So I have 2 JS functions, loadReport is calling getCurrentReport. I've checked that I do have the correct object before returning, and yet the caller does not receive that object. Why?

```
    getCurrentReport(id) {
        this.reports.forEach(e => {
            if (e.id === id) {
                console.log(e);     // This prints exactly the object that I want
                return e;    // So I assume I should get this object..
            }
        });
    }

    async loadReport(id) {
        var report = this.getCurrentReport(id);
        console.log("Getting:");
        console.log(report);    // And yet I'm getting undefined here?
    },
```

Someone please explain to me?

Comment: It depends what `this` is in the context of the call to `loadReport`. Chances are it isn't what you think it is.

Comment: "_So I assume I should get this object.._" Incorrect, that `return` just breaks the current `forEach` round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCurrentReport` is not returning anything, therefore `report` will be `undefined`.

I assume you are using the `forEach` to try and 'find' the report, if so, you should use Array's `find` function

```
getCurrentReport(id) {
   return this.reports.find(e => e.id === id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are returning e inside a forEach . Try declaring a variable outside forEach and assign e to it and return it outside forEach

Refer below

```js
    function getCurrentReport(id) {
      //declare a variable to hold e
        let currentReport;
        //sample arrray taken
        [{id:1,name:"abc"}, {id:2,name:"xyz"}].forEach(e => {
            if (e.id === id) {
                console.log(e);     // This prints exactly the object that I want
                currentReport = e;    // So I assume I should get this object..
            }
        });
        
        //return here
        return currentReport
    }

    async function loadReport(id) {
        var report = getCurrentReport(id);
        console.log("Getting:");
        console.log(report);    // And yet I'm getting undefined here?
    }

    
    setTimeout(() => {
      loadReport(1)
    }, 1000);
```